# Execute a program with a custom .ini path

Tags: file, configuration, batch-file, exe, ini

I make a fair amount portable Apps for personal use and they work perfectly for the most part. I do, however, find it quite frustrating that if I run them on another computer none of my preferences are retained, as a program always looks in appData for the configuration files (which obviously don't exist on another system), so I'm wondering whether there is some kind of command line to launch an .exe with a custom .ini location.

I'm asking this firstly because Google has proved fruitless (once again) and secondly because I know it's possible - I've actually done this before, but with only one of my Apps. I accomplished this by launching the App via the command `programFile.exe -f configFile.ini /s` (I have also seen `programFile.exe -d -f configFile.ini /s` elsewhere). Naturally, I thought I would try to apply this to some other Apps but it seems it only works for that particular App.

So, is there a command/switch that I am unaware of that will do this for an .exe file?

Thanks

Comment: IMHO there isn't a generally way to solve this. Program switches can be different for each single program, as they are handled by the programs themself

Comment: There's no switches or commands? No hacks/mods to force a program to look in one directory over the default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on each executable file you are using. Some have support for what you are looking for, and some don't. Some programs don't even use .ini files. What you should look for is if each and every program you use have support for user data custom location.

### Edit

The only case where generic arguments would be avaialble for a group of EXE files is if they are generated with the same tool, which automatically provides these arguments for you. InstallShield and MSI install programs have that kind of feature (with the silent install and automated installation for instance).

I suggest you look into the tool you are using to generate your portable Apps, and see if it does provide those generic arguments for you, and how they work. If it does not have that feature, then look into the Apps you were able to specify a custom location for your INI file. Somewhere into the code, there must be a piece of code that handles the arguments you specify to the EXE file and handles them. You should share that piece of code with your other Apps, to make sure they provide the same arguments list.

Comment: As I said to jeb: "There's no switches or commands? No hacks/mods to force a program to look in one directory over the default?"

Comment: No, there isn't. As I said, it depends on each software. If the development team decided they support an argument `-i <ini path>`, then it works for that executable, and that executable only. I have updated my answer with a case where generic arguments could be available, you would have to check if it applies to your case.

Comment: Okay, that's great thanks. I'll try it a bit later and get back to me. :)